# Error when get token "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"

Tags: c#, authentication, thinktecture-ident-server

There are many similar topics with same issue, but nothing relevant to my issue on Identity server.
Probably am still failing to understand this.
I am trying to implement identity server authentication by recreating [this sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/MvcCodeFlowClientManual)

[Sample GetToken() method](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/MvcCodeFlowClientManual/Controllers/CallbackController.cs) is working fine, but when I call `GetToken()` method in my application I get error

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation
>   procedure.
>   I am realy not sure how semple working fine, but my code does not.

This is code

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetToken()
{
    var client = new TokenClient(
        "https://localhost:44331/connect/authorize",
        "codeclient",
        "secret");

    var code = Request.QueryString["code"];
    var tempState = await GetTempStateAsync();
    Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut("TempState");

    var response = await client.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(
        code,
        "http://localhost/UniSrv.Client.Web/callback"
            );

    //... more code
   }
```

It breaks on `RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync`.
I am using same certificate as sample aplication on identiy server host app.
Do I need certificate on client? If yes, why than sample application working without that? 
Thank for help to resolve this issue.

Comment: I believe this has something to do with ssl certificate. Can you try using a https callback endpoint as with the sample?

Comment: Yes that was problem. I coluld not use ssl because I used 'Local IIS'. When I changed to 'IIS Expres' it was fine. @rawel you can answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like SSL Certificate validation failed. Try Using HTTPS on the callback endpoint. 
Note: https transport security must be enabled when OAuth/OpenId connect tokens are used.